# What would be the shortest way to write/create an int[] with 3 unique random numbers using a stream in java?

Tags: java, random, int

I am currently using the following code:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> numbersMap = new HashMap<>();
return IntStream.generate(() -> (int)(10 * Math.random() + 1))
                .filter(i -> numbersMap.put(i, i) == null)
                .limit(3)
                .toArray();
```

For example, I am wondering if there is a way to do this without the use of a `HashMap`, since I am only using the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IntStream.generate(() -> (int) (10 * Math.random() + 1))
         .distinct()
         .limit(3)
         .toArray();
```

or

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(1, 10 + 1)
                           .distinct()
                           .limit(3)
                           .toArray();
```

Comment: Cool! Didn't know distinct() could be used after generate()